# Can't create a CIContext from a 3.0 EAGLContext

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, core-image, opengl-es-3.0

If I initialize the `EAGLContext` like this

```
_eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2]
```

the program runs fine but using `kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3`, the following code causes a crash:

```
_ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_eaglContext options:options];
```

`CIContext` class reference states that *"The OpenGL ES context must support OpenGL ES 2.0"* but I was under the impression that 3.0 was supposed to be backwards compatible...

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

From the console output:

"CIContexts can only be created with ES 2.0 EAGLContexts"